# No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider when using environment vars

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cloud

I have a terraform script that works locally but when I publish to Terraform Cloud it errors as below:

```
Error: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
        Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
        providing credentials for the AWS Provider
 on main.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
  1: provider "aws" {
```

The i have set the same variables in the same way on other successfully working deployments but it doesn't seem to be pulling the credentials through.

Any direction on troubleshooting would be appreciated

[image: Variables setting]

Comment: Should the first variable be named `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`? Source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS environment variables should be `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. If you have multiple AWS Keys you can also select a specific profile within your `$HOME/.aws/credentials` with `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable.

Comment: perfect thanks, I knew it would be something obvious that I was just not seeing

Comment: will this apply to terraform cloud as well?